# Can't Get Model to Pass Rspec with ActiveRecord Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Model: payment.rb

```
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :loan

  def self.previous_payments(id)
    where(loan_id: id)
  end

end
```

All I am trying to do is test to make sure a payment is found if it has the correct loan_id

Test:

```
describe '#self.previous_payments' do
  let(:loan) {Loan.create!(id: 1, funded_amount: 1000.0)}
  let(:payment_one) {Payment.create!(amount: 100.0, loan_id: 1)}
  let(:payment_test) {Payment.previous_payments(1)}

  it 'retrieves all the payments made for a specific loan' do
    expect(payment_test.first.loan_id).to eql(1)
  end
end
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
expected: 1
got: #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

And it looks like [] means that  no records were even found?

Any help at all would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rspec's `let` syntax is lazy, meaning that `loan` and `payment_one` won't exist until they are explicitly called in your test. Because `payment_test` doesn't make any explicit calls to `loan` or `payment_one`, it returns an empty relation. If you use `let!`, your variables won't be lazily loaded:

```
let!(:loan) {Loan.create!(id: 1, funded_amount: 1000.0)}
let!(:payment_one) {Payment.create!(amount: 100.0, loan_id: 1)}
```

You could also do something like

```
loan.reload
payment_one.reload
expect(payment_test.first.loan_id).to eql(1)
```

within the test to force `loan` and `payment_one` to be loaded.

Comment: Ahhh thanks a ton james00794! Worked perfect. Never would have guessed about putting "let! instead of "let".